# How do i stop runnable after a specific time

Tags: android

Am having a handler method which is running in a interval of 5ms. I want to stop this execution after certain period? Any suggestion please

Comment: use flag for that...

Comment: have you read `Handler`'s documentation? it has several methods to remove pending `Runnable`s / `Message`s

Comment: Add a check. If the condition is true break from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage a handler(runnable) by creating an instance member for the handler and runnable, then managing the handler in the Activity Lifecycle methods.

```
private Handler myHandler;
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    //Do Something
}
};
```

Start the runnable with handler.post.

```
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
myHandler = new Handler();
myHandler.post(myRunnable);

}
```

If the runnable hasn't executed by the time `onStop` is called, we don't want to run it. Remove the callback in the `onStop` method:

```
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
mHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
 }
```

Comment: what if i want to stop it after some time? like 10seconds